# Excluding one node from a for-each loop XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have a for-each loop, and I want to exclude an element based on an attribute value. I came across this

```
<xsl:for-each select="*[not(self::element-to-ignore)]">
```

But I am unsure how to apply it to the following context.

```
<table>
  <xsl:for-each select="document('document.xml')//area">
    <xsl:sort select="@description"/>
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="@description"/></td>
      </tr>
  </xsl:for-each>
</table>
```

I want to exclude one node from my iterated list

Is there a more correct way to achieve this?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please show an example of `document.xml` and explain which nodes you want to exclude. Also state if using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0 (please do this in all your XSLT questions).

Comment: Hi again michael, the document information is so long ! ill try condense it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you mean

```
<xsl:for-each select="*[local-name() != 'element-to-ignore']">
```

or if you really mean "attribute value"

```
<xsl:for-each select="*[@attribute != 'value-to-ignore']">
```

Comment: No, they mean `*[not(self::element-to-ignore)]` and they are correct. Your version ignores the namespace and can potentially exclude more nodes than intended.

Comment: This is exactly what I was after thank you the second solution did the job, sorry if my question wasnt as clear, I tried my best to make as clear as possible

Comment: Glad to help - but you learn that better wording the question might avoid confusion